# "The proverbial wedding ring"?

Tags: meaning, phrases

In old books, I keep coming accross the saying,

> ...is so transparent it could pass through the proverbial wedding ring.

What does this mean?

Comment: You could [look it up](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/proverbial).

Comment: @Robusto - I'm not sure that just looking up the definition of "proverbial" would help the OP to understand the meaning of "the proverbial wedding ring"...

Comment: Welcome to ELU!  We welcome questions that include the research you've already done on the subject.  That way, you learn and we all share the knowledge.  After doing your research, if you still have a question, please repost.

Comment: @Robusto if the OP tried looking it up, they'd be up the proverbial creek without a paddle. (In this case, I used "proverbial" as a way to avoid saying a certain word, whereas that doesn't apply in this text)

Answer (score 14):

Some makers of some fine, light cloths — or the garments made of them — will boast that because they are so fine, you can roll them up and pass them through a wedding ring. (You are supposed to be able to do this with a Shetland shawl, a *superfino* Panama hat, a ring pashmina [see where the name is from?] and other items.)

The *proverbial* in this case means "often talked about in a common idiom, saying or cliché", so it's directly addressing the fact that other people have used the same statement before.

Personally, I dislike this use of *proverbial*: It's almost like saying "I'm going to write or say something corny and tired now, but that's okay because I'm pointing out that I know it's corny and tired". When I find myself using it, I try not just to cut it, but to cut the whole passage and re-write.

Comment: I always thought 'proverbial' meant pertaining to an actual proverb - I'm not aware of any such proverbs in this context and I would also have been confused by this.

Comment: To restate your last paragraph:  The author is [hanging the proverbial lampshade](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/LampshadeHanging) on it.

Comment: @Kyudos *proverbial* certainly can mean that, but see e.g. Merriam-Webster: "that has become a proverb or byword : commonly spoken of <the proverbial smoking gun>".

Comment: @BenJackson Yes, only but lampshade hanging can be enjoyable, when it's done better than just saying "I am using a well-known trope".

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unusual_units_of_measurement